# How to transfer files between Guest OSs (all Windows) running over VMware Workstation?

Tags: vmware

I have a project scenario where 3 Virtual Machine (all Windows OS) need to transfer file in a serial order (The host OS is also Windows).
Like **VM1 -> VM2 -> VM3** and again in reverse direction **VM3 -> VM2 -> VM1**.
Here **VM2** will act like a server where I need to process the file retrieved from **VM3** and then send it to **VM1**.

So how do I set up the Network Interface between all the 3 VMs?

Comment: What type of network are you using for the guests?

Comment: I cannot use any Internet in this scenario. So I need to use something like intranet, Coz this is totally a offline demonstration.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: how did you set up the network interface(s) in the guests?

Comment: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html

Comment: @Marcelo That is what I need to know.